USB debugging quickly gives ANR on breakpoint and debugging ends
I get ANR after some seconds within breakpoint while USB debugging. Once ANR, the debugging ends and can't inspect the values for long enough in Visual Studio. Notice: also when this happens the app goes to the background and when brought to the front it's restarted.
Here are the output lines right from the moment the debugging ends (last output lines, only 3):
[libc] Requested dump for pid 22650 (com.companyname.appname)
[Looper] dumpMergedQueue
[OplusLooperMsgDispatcher] dumpMsgWhenAnr

I tryed "Select debugging app" on Android but it did nothing.
Workaround 1
Debug in the qemu emulator, but if I need to test the camera I am in problem again because I tryed to use the camera simulator but couldn't move the protagonist.
Update:
To move the protagonist or change the sight angle, keep the alt key pressed and use the WASD keys to move front/back/left/right, use the Q and E keys to move up/down, and use the mouse to look in any direction. You will find the configured images on the wall and table in the dinning room.
Workaround 2
Do not use breakpoints and just log information to VS Output with System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine, and debug based on that information.
Ideal solution
The solution to this question would ideally be to be able to examine values in a breakpoint for as long as I want with USB debugging, I guess that's how it's supposed to work.
How to reproduce

Create a new solution with ".NET MAUI App" template.
Place a breakpoint in the OnCounterClicked method.
Run USB debug with Android device.
Reach the breakpoint and wait around 10 seconds.
See debug ending with "dumpMsgWhenAnr" in VS Output.


Debugging on Visual Studio 17.10.1 for Windows with Android 14 device.

Can you provide the code for the breakpoint part? What features are you running when the ANR appears?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT it doesn't really matter, the breakpoint can be anywhere in the code, i.e. being at any breakpoint wont last more than around 10 seconds before USB debug aborts with ANR. Maybe the only exception is if the breakpoint is not in the main thread. Not sure what you mean by "features", but USB debugging is a Visual Studio and Android developer options feature. If you meant about which libraries I am using, just create a new solution with ".NET MAUI App" template. The untouched template project still has this problem, for example place a breakpoint at the OnCounterClicked method.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT just added a How to reproduce part to the question.

Why use QEMU Simulator? MAUI supports the use of Andorid simulator, have you tried using it?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT looks like Quemu is the emulator that runs Android for Visual Studio, it's the emulator that comes packaged with VS, for debugging Android app. I checked task manager and Quemu is there.

Sorry, I meant to say QEMU (not QUEMU).

@ShuowenHe-MSFT Thanks for trying the steps to reproduce. It must be the phone, as you suggest, because all I did was run the default project without any changes. My phone is Realme brand, probably the Android environment developed by Realme has this issue.

My device is Pixel 5. According to your problem, I did the following test:
Create a default MAUI project, deploy the project to the Pixel5 device, and set a breakpoint in the OnCounterClicked method. After the project starts, click the button and wait for 10seconds, the result is that no ANR appears.
You can try to update VS to the latest version (currently the latest version is 17.10.3). In addition, you can try to run the default project on other Android devices to check whether the same problem occurs.

Just to be sure: did you try on physical device or virtual device? I don't have problem on virtual devices (via emulator), I have the problem when USB debugging in my physical device.

Yes, I tried the steps not only on physical device(Pixel5), but also on android simulator, and I didn't meet your problem.
